# DNN module with multiple sqlprovider install scripts

Tags: dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

**Context**

- I have a DNN 7 module that uses multiple tables.
- I have the CREATE TABLE statements in separate files for clarity and ease of use.
- My module's .dnn file has multiple entries for each script under the
  components tag.

**Problem**

When I install the module, only that last install script is executed (in the case of the example "CreateProductWidths"), ignoring the others.

**Question**

How can I run multiple scripts in separate files during installation? I have a total of 15 tables in this module, so it would not be conducive to have all of their definitions in one script. If it's too hard, I may be doing it wrong and I'm open to advice. Thanks.

**Example**

```
<component type="Script">
    <scripts>
        <basePath>DesktopModules\ProductManager</basePath>
        <script type="Install">
          <path>Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider</path>
          <name>CreateProductCategories.SqlDataProvider</name>
          <version>00.00.01</version>
        </script>
        <script type="Install">
          <path>Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider</path>
          <name>CreateProductFamilies.SqlDataProvider</name>
          <version>00.00.01</version>
        </script>
        <script type="Install">
          <path>Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider</path>
          <name>CreateProductWidths.SqlDataProvider</name>
          <version>00.00.01</version>
        </script>
        <script type="UnInstall">
          <path>Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider</path>
          <name>Uninstall.SqlDataProvider</name>
          <version>00.00.01</version>
        </script>
    </scripts>
</component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dilon,

I believe the DNN installation only supports one script file per version.  Most of the time a modules CREATE TABLE/SPROC/VIEW script is in its first version, ie: 01.00.00.  Then subsequent scripts will have alter table scripts or whatever is needed to change for that version.  This is good practice because it allows you to manage your versioning.  Also your scripts should be re-runnable in case the installation is repaired.  Therefore your CREATE statements should be prefaced with IF EXISTS statements.

That being said, if you want to break out your scripts, you can set the package version to 01.00.00.

IE:

<package name="Module.Name" type="Module" version="00.01.00">

Then version your scripts differently, ie: "00.00.01", "00.00.02", "00.00.03", etc.  DNN will run all scripts whose version is **less than or equal to** the package version number.  It will also run them in version number order.

Comment: What happens if you zip your Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider (the entire Providers folder), add that to your manifest as a ResourceFile which the installer successfully unpacks, but the SQL scripts don't get run. Do you still have to add a separate component elements for each script?

Comment: @Jacques, if the scripts are in the package, but they don't run, it's usually one of two problems: the version of the module package is lower than the versions on the scripts in the manifest, OR the manifest path is incorrect. Example: <script type="Install"> <path>Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider</path> <name>00.00.01.SqlDataProvider</name> <version>00.00.01</version> </script>

Comment: So essentially what you're saying is that there's no point in zipping up your sqldataprovider files because you have to separately reference them in the manifest anyway? I was thinking that Dnn might have a simpler way to do this.

Comment: No, you need to do both: zip the script files in the package and reference the script files in your DNN manifest.